# Constructing a solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Suppose we have a smooth function $u(t,x)$ such that $u_{tt}=u_{xx}$

I want to construct a function $v(t,x)$ such that $v_{t}=u_{x}$ and $v_{x}=u_{t}$

My approach:

Let $v(t,x)$ be a function.

Let $v_{tx}=u_{xx}$: this implies $v_{t}=u_{x}$

Let $v_{xt}=u_{tt}$: this implies $v_{x}=u_{t}$

Since $u_{tt}=u_{xx}$, then we have $v_{tx}=v_{xt}$

$\therefore$ Our function $v(t,x)$ must pertain to $C^2$, its second partial derivatives must be continuous.

Is this correct?